# tuple result in slick 3 DBIO

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

There is a table with key, values.

There is an another table with auto incremented PK.

Take the value for the key from the first table. If not present insert and 
return defaulted value.
Query on other table based on it.

Return filtered result and the value.

So I could try:

```
def lastLogs(limit: Long = 666): Future[(Long, Seq[VLogEntry])] = {
  val q: DBIO[(Long, Seq[VLogEntry])] = {
    for {
      existing <- kvTable.filter(_.key === "log").result.headOption
      conf = existing getOrElse KV(key = "log", value = "0")
      last = conf.value.toLong
      rds = vLogTable.filter(_.id > last).take(limit).result
      _ <- kvTable.insertOrUpdate(conf)
    } yield {
      (last, rds)
    }
  }
  db.run(q)
}
```

This gives compile error:

```
found   : HipDAO.this.domain.dbConfig.profile.StreamingProfileAction[Seq[HipDAO.this.domain.VLogTable ...

required: Seq[db.types.Types.VLogEntry]
```

In Slick 2 I could call list or result on queries in session.
How do I to this in Slick 3.

Comment: your `rds = ` should be `rds <- `. Not sure if that solves everything, it would be useful to see the full error and where it was reported.

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured it right after I wrote this post, but left it in case someone comes with how to read this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the iterations of what could be done I came to:

```
def lastLogs(limit: Long = 666): Future[(Long, Seq[VLogEntry])] = {
  val q: DBIO[(Long, Seq[VLogEntry])] = {
    for {
      existing <- kvTable.filter(_.key === "log").result.headOption
      conf = existing getOrElse KV(key = "log", value = "0")
      _ <- kvTable.insertOrUpdate(conf)
      last = conf.value.toLong
      rds <- vLogTable.filter(_.id > last).take(limit).result
    } yield {
      (last, rds)
    }
  }
  db.run(q)
}
```

Since difference is only 2 characters this seems like an easy fix.
Internet is devoid from what `StreamingProfileAction` is, and how to read this messages.
Some insight might come from reading [essential slick 3](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html)

Eventually, how I saw it, it's a monad, you are supposed to flatMap it.